# How to debug an IDAPython script from within IDA?

Tags: python, idapython, ida

IDAPython is great plugin in IDA. It is so handy to write small script to decode, decrypt or fix (patch) a binary in IDA.  I can just write, load and run a script, and can use `print` for the usual shotgun debugging. But when I develop a bigger IDAPython script, I need a way to debug it.

I have searched and found that I can debug IDAPython with [WingIDE](http://wingware.com/doc/howtos/idapython) but I want to find another that doesn't require WingIDE. Is there another way to debug IDAPython scripts?

Comment: i guess i am old fashioned, i use 'print'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: This seems to be obsolete.

You can debug IDAPython scripts using Python Tools for Visual Studio. It is completely free, and very easy to use.

See [this tutorial](http://sark.readthedocs.org/en/latest/debugging.html) for this information.

Comment: The tutorial is wrong or obsolete. I repeated the steps with Visual Studio 2019 and IDA 7.2, it doesn't work. When Visual Studio starts to attach to IDA, it reports error. The error text is very informative ;) it is "General error occurred"...

Comment: Thanks. Edited the answer to reflect it.

Comment: That `enable_attach(secret="` part is wrong. Needs to be something like `ptvsd.enable_attach(address=('localhost', 5678))`: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25102/how-to-setup-vscode-with-idapython/26069#26069

Answer (score 8):

You can do this.  Last summer I worked with Hexrays and WingIDE guys and got this working.  In fact its in the docs!

http://wingware.com/doc/howtos/idapython

It rocks.

Riley

Answer (score 4):

As far as i know there's no way to debug python inside IDA.

There are, however, a few python tools you could use to debug your own code.
but it will essentially require you to develop your own python IDE/debugger utilities around the built-in python debugging tools.

I'm listing the possible methods by order of complexity (simplest first):

**Compiling and running your own python code from python**
The more basic approach is using the python `compile` built-in function to compile python code into bytecode, executing that with `eval` or `exec` (also built-in functions). `compile` returns an `AST` (Abstract Syntax Tree) object you can further manipulate/investigate.

**Using The python debugger (from python)**
If you want more advanced debugging abilities, python has it's own built-in python debugger module called `pdb`. You only need to tell `pdb` what python code to execute, and it'll spawn a debugger interface similar to `gdb`, the command line debugger lets you set conditional breakpoints, manipulate and analyze python code, and use most of the usual debugging tools.

**Using the python debugging framework**
the python debugger is built on top of python's `bdb` (basic debugger), it is a class implementing debugging functionality and can be used from within IDA's python command line. If you're going to use the `bdb` you'll have to create your own tools and UI around these utilities.

Edit:
I saw WingIDE only now. since OP didn't specify what exactly is the issue using WingIDE, I hope at least one of the methods will be relevant.

Comment: I would imagine the issue is that it isn't cheap.

Comment: @cb88: 45$ vs the ~500$ IDA costs?.. sounds a bit odd but i guess it may be the reason.