# How to setup VSCode with IDAPython?

Tags: ida, debugging, idapython, remote

Is it possible to remotely debug IDAPyhton scripts using VSCode and ptvsd? I found a few tutorials on the net, but no one is working. In the past, using the same protocol I was able to connect to Maya from VSCode and to remotely debug Pymel scripts. So, from IDA python console I entered:

```
ptvsd.enable_attach(address=('localhost', 5678), redirect_output=True)
```

and eventually:

```
ptvsd.wait_for_attach(60)
```

A Python MsgBox appears telling a script is running... Now in VSCode I started the script to be debugged using the standard json configuration file for attaching to a remote debugger, but the connection is always refused.
I tried to change the port (3528, 3000), the address (0.0.0.0) and to remove the redirect_output flag. No matter what, I wasn't able to connect. I tried also:

```
ptvsd.break_into_debugger()
```

But again, no luck.

As a second question, is there a way to make the import statement recognize IDAPython modules (idaapi, idc, idc_bytes and so on) or to use autocompletion? I know IDAPython is bundled with IDA and not installed in site-packages, but I wonder if is there a solution (not to execute the script outside of IDA, but to have the modules and keywords recognized).

Comment: Worth noting `break_into_debugger` only works if the debugger is already attached. First I took it to do what `wait_for_attach` is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Something this should work for `ptvsd`:

```
        {
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "debugServer": 5678,
            "showReturnValue": true,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "redirectOutput": true,
        }
```

You may need to insert an explicit `breakpoint()` in the code.

For IntelliSense in VSCode there's `PYTHONPATH` or

```
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "..."
    ],
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "..."
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

[**idacode**](https://github.com/ioncodes/idacode/tree/master/idacode) offers a wonderful integration between VSCode and idapython.

The github repo is the best place to find the **IDA plugin**, and there is a **VSCode extension** under the same name available in the extension repository.

If your IDA installation is not in the default location, see the readme in the github repo.

Once installed, you enable a local listening server within IDA from the plugin menu, and then in VSCode you open a workspace in the directory containing your python code. Using the command list (ctrl+shift+P), type 'IDA' and choose one of the options to connect with or without a debugger. Then each time you save the python script, it will be executed in IDA.

If you wish to use [**vscodium**](https://vscodium.com/) instead of vscode, you will need to select "install from *.vsix" in the extension manager menu and choose the vsix which you can [**download here**.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Layle.idacode)